# jqueryui dialog, direction of slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery dialog and want to slide on show. How do I specify the direction of the slide?

```
$('.selector').dialog({ show: 'slide' });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering these links :

<strike>- [Dialog - show with effect and options](http://www.nabble.com/Dialog---show-with-effect-and-options-td23394129s27240.html) (May 2009, so not **old**)</strike>
 - [Is possible to have more granular control over jQuery UI Dialog Widget’s show/hide method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531344/is-possible-to-have-more-granular-control-over-jquery-ui-dialog-widgets-show-hid/818960#818960)

It doesn't seem to be possible, at least with current versions...

Answer (score 3):

To control the direction, you can use 'slideUp'/'slideDown' instead of 'slide'.

```
$('.selector').dialog({ show: 'slideDown', hide: 'slideUp' });
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me with JQuery 2 and JQuery UI 1.11:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({show: {effect:"slide", direction:"right"}})
```

Note that direction "right" slides FROM right to left.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the problem in this way:
I have edit the UI file "jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" in Dialog section

Original code:

```
d.show(e.show);// <--or iDialog.show(options.show) in ui.dialog.js
```

Modified code:

```
d.show(e.show,e.showOpt); // or iDialog.show(options.show,options.showOpt) in ui.dialog.js
```

I create my dialog adding a new parameter "showOpt" that can contain the jquery effect options

```
$j( "#dialog_box" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    width:500,
    height:500,
    show: "slide",
    showOpt: {direction: 'up'}
    });
```